# Is AV only needed because of human users?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, anti-virus

I rent a VPS, and as an a kneejerk reaction (it's a Windows server), I got AV for it.

Given that I do very little with it as a logged-in user (I use it as a web server), bar install my own software on it, and occasionally download Microsoft libraries and whatnot, is there a need for AV at all?

I think my question boils down to this: can a machine become infected without a human user being involved, and if so, how? Or do I only need AV to protect my server from my own foolish actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can a machine become infected without a human user being involved, and
>   if so, how

Yes, by any number of vectors. Most likely are vulnerabilities in whatever software you're running on the server, but also possible (though rare) are remotely-exploitable operating system vulnerabilities.

I would not feel comfortable running without an up-to-date antivirus.